# Warnings при компиляции TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-2.x, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

Я работаю с **Tensor Flow** на **python 2.7** и у меня возникают следующие предупреждения. С чем они связаны, я не понимаю.

*2017-09-06 22:28:21.659388: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.*

*2017-09-06 22:28:21.659414: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.*

*2017-09-06 22:28:21.659419: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.*

*2017-09-06 22:28:21.659423: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.*

*2017-09-06 22:28:21.659427: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.*

Пример модели:

```
 def baseline_model():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model


estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Они говорят о том, что TensorFlow, собранный из исходников, может работать быстрее на Вашей машине. Эти инструкции по умолчанию не включены в доступные сборки. Думаю, что они совместимы с большим количеством процессоров.

Чтобы отключить эти предупреждения, выполните следующие действия:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: Или. как вариант, можно пересобрать tensorflow из исходников. Впрочем, если всё обучение идёт на GPU прироста быстродействия практически никакого не будет.